# Private code generation functions in D?

Tags: templates, namespaces, d, private, template-meta-programming

I'm writing a templated struct in D, which uses string `mixin`s and compile time functions for some of its functionality.  Basically, it is in this format:

```
string genCode(T)() {
    // ...
}

struct MyTemplate(T) {
    mixin(genCode!(T)());
    // ...
}
```

Looking at this, `genCode()` is clearly an implementation detail of my template class; making it public exposes logic which should really be private, and which could be subject to change.  It also clutters the module's exported namespace.

When I try to make it `private`, however, D throws an error.  As far as I can tell, the expression in the string `mixin` is evaluated in whatever scope `MyTemplate` is instantiated in, which caused D to claim that the symbol `genCode()` is not declared.

Is there any way around this?  Do I just have to live with `genCode()` as a public function, or is there some way I can hide it?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "D throws an error"?  What is the error, exactly?

Comment: D says that the identifier `genCode` is not declared.  It compiles fine if `genCode` is declared public.

Comment: Have you tried `protected` or `package`?

Answer (score 1):

Please provide code examples which demonstrate the subject.

```
module x.gen;
private string genCode(T)() {
    return T.stringof ~ " a;";
}
```

---

```
module x.test;

import x.gen;
struct MyTemplate(T) {
    mixin(genCode!(T)());
}

void main() {
    MyTemplate!int m;
    m.a = 3;
}
```

The access level desired must be select: public, private, package. These are the only controls provided for access levels. If anything else is desired it isn't possible.

Related Bugs:

- https://issues.dlang.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3108
- https://issues.dlang.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8716
- https://issues.dlang.org/show_bug.cgi?id=7961